Dual boot system: Upgrade LTS 22.04 to 24.04 failed: reboot shows just cursor blinking after choosing "ubuntu" to start
I am running a Dell Latitude E6500 with Windows 10 and xubuntu. All os are patched and have the newest softwre. Two day ago I upgraded from LTS 22.04 to 24.04. everything seemed to run well. The last task was to reboot the system what I did. Grub showed up as usually and I choosed "Ubuntu", the fist entry. All I can get is a blinking cursor in the upper left corner of the screen.
Fortunately I can start Windows ...
During the upgrade process I was asked to choose whether to keep the old startup/boot configuration what I agreed to because ist worked fine since than.
Thank you very much for any advise.
Ronald

Is this old BIOS only system? Ubuntu is getting too large for old BIOS systems. Kubuntu or lightweight flavors work much better. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie Do you get grub menu? Then can you boot recovery mode? Older nVidia  are only supported by Nouveau open source driver.

Hello oldfred, it is a BIOS System. I can enter the boot menue and start the recovery mode. Also I did all the tasks (clean, dpkg, fsck, etc.) mentioned in the recovery mode. I am running xubuntu which I wanted to upgrade because this option was offered. When I reboot the system and I choose the first entry (ubuntu) I get a blinking cursor in the upper left corner.

Other difference with recovery mode is that it adds "nomodeset" to boot. With first boot stanza, edit grub with e and manually add nomodeset in place of quiet splash on linux line. Without quiet splash you also see boot process which may show where it stops, often several lines before last line posted. All those lines also are in log files.

I tried to add "nomodeset" to the "grub" file using a live usb-stick and mousepad. But in the end I could not run "sudo update-grub". The path /cow.....  could not be found. May be the recovery mode allows me to do so. I think that worked but it did not help to get the system start. After reboot I still see the cursor in the left upper corner  ...

You cannot edit the live installer, it is a combined DVD/Flash drive configuration. And /cow is copy on write or the live installer. Can you edit from booting the actual install?

You are right, sorry. I did it using the recovery mode and added "nomodeset" but it did not change the behavior of the start procedure.

My old laptop never would boot Ubuntu, but booted Kubuntu and other lighter weight flavors or the server version with  a light weight gui.

That's not the problem in my case. Xubuntu 2as doing very well until I upgraded to the new LTS version.

Did you remove quiet splash from Linux line to see boot process and then where it may have stopped working?

No I did not because I read in "ask ubuntu" that I should add "nomodeset" and that is what I did. I will remove "quiet splash" and come back. Thank you.

Meanwhile I changed the entry in /etc/default/grub to just "nomodeset" but I got no other result. All can see ist the blinking cursor in the upper left corner of the screen. May grub ist affected and needs to be repaired. I used the given option in the recovery mode but got no result.

Typically nomodeset is built into the recovery mode (without quit splash). It is only for temporary use until correct driver is installed.

Well in the end I decided to delete ubuntu. Writing the mbr failed but Icould remove the two ext4 partions. Now I am doing everything new again starting to set up Windows 10 and the software and data. The next step is to install ubuntu which will run on a new system I guess.

Thank you very much!
